# Jquery events and selector issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I'm a newbie with jquery so forgive me if my question is not well formulated, I just don't have a good semantic clue at how to formulate it.

I'm presenting content from a wordpress website using a nested carousel (using twitter bootstrap)

```
<div id="outer-carousel" class="carousel slide well" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <div id="nested-carousel1" class="carousel slide well">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <center>
                        item1
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item2
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item3
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#nested-carousel1" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#nested-carousel1" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">          
            <div id="nested-carousel2" class="carousel slide well">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item4
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item5
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item6
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#nested-carousel2" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#nested-carousel2" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">          
            <div id="nested-carousel3" class="carousel slide well">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item7
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item8
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <center>
                        item9
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#nested-carousel3" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#nested-carousel3" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span1">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#outer-carousel" data-slide-to="0">
            carousel1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span1">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#outer-carousel" data-slide-to="1">
            carousel2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span1">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#outer-carousel" data-slide-to="2">
            carousel3
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The "outer" carousel changes slides when the user clicks on a thumbnail

Each slide consist in an "inner" carousel that is manipulated with left and right arrows.

I have a problem with this though, because when I slide the "outer" carousel, the first "item" of the "inner" carousel should be assigned the "active" class.

The good news is: twitter bootstrop provides a "slid" event when changing slides.

so I could set the class of the first "item" in the correct "inner" carousel.

```
    $('#outer-carousel').on('slid', function(e) {    
    // insert class assignment here
});
```

see all this in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4hgcY/29/

My problem, however, is that I want do do this ONLY when the "outer" carousel is slid. But as you can see in the jsfiddle, the "slid" event fired by sliding an inner carousel causes the above Jquery to call the function as well...

what should I do? I've tried using selectors

```
    $('#outer-carousel').on('slid', '#outer-carousel",function(e) {    
    // insert class assignment here
});
```

But it dosn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ensure that the event happened on the target carousel.

```
if (this === e.target) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it works :-)
Now I'm a bit confused with the notion of "this" when outside of an object but I'm sure I'll find what I need on the webs :-)